# use of a local variable in C# Parallel.For

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, for-loop, parallel.foreach

I am new to using Parallel.For and am stuck on the following.

Within my For loop I use a pointer offset (iPathMatrixOffset) that I need to increase by a certain fixed number (nStages) every iteration. Basically after r iterations that offset will have the value r * nStages.

I currently declare this variable inside the loop and set it to r*nStages.

This I think is not the most efficient way - this is performance critical code (that's why I am using pointer based code here) - I want to try and see if incrementing it with nStages at the end of each iteration is faster.

But I don't know how to declare a variable that is local to the thread only and I can't figure it out from MSDN.

This must be a common question ... surely I am overlooking something obvious.

Help appreciated.

current code:

```
Parallel.For(0, nStates, r =>
{
    int iPathMatrixOffset;
    double local_maxV;

    iPathMatrixOffset = r * nStages;

    // some code, calculates local_maxV

    // store result in path matrix
    fixed (double* pPathMatrix = &PathMatrix[0, t])
    {
        *(pPathMatrix + iPathMatrixOffset) = local_maxV;
    }
});
```

would like to do something like:

```
Parallel.For(0, nStates, r =>
{
    double local_maxV;
    // some code

    // store result in path matrix
    fixed (double* pPathMatrix = &PahMatrix[0, t])
    {
        *(pPathMatrix + iPathMatrixOffset) = local_maxV;
    }
    iPathMatrixOffset += nStages;

});
```

Comment: Have you tried it _without_ pointers to verify that using pointers is significantly faster?

Comment: You are declaring iPathMatrixOffset locally to the thread running the for loop in the top example.  You can't use the same variable for iPathMatrixOffset value in different threads either, since the value of it will likely chance between when you set it and when you want to use it.

Comment: Do you really expect that avoiding a single multiplication will have a measurable impact on your code? What did your profiling show?

Comment: Yes, using pointers here makes a huge difference. This in an inner loop (there is another one around it) that is executed over 1,500,000 times and the execution of this block went from 6 seconds to 1.5 seconds using pointers.

Comment: cont'd: anything in this loop needs to be as fast as possible and this is one of the last tweaks that I can make. Adding n times is probably faster than multiplying n times.

Comment: if you do `iPathMatrixOffset += nStages;` then you have to run your loop sequential and cannot use Parallel.For - which defeats your purpose. I think current code is better.